# Calculate Total Sum of Square Inconsistency

Tags: r, k-means

I am attempting to write my own function for total sum of square, within sum of square, and between sum of square in R Studio for my own implementation of k-means.

I've successfully written the function for within sum of square, but I'm having difficulty with total sum of square (and thus bss).  The result I get is significantly larger than what R's own kmeans function computes.  I'm confused because I am following exactly what formulas provide.  Here is my data:

```
A =

36     3
73     3
30     3
49     3
47    11
47    11
 0     7
46     5
16     3
52     4
 0     8
21     3
 0     4
57     6
31     5
 0     6
40     3
31     5
38     4
 0     5
59     4
61     6
48     7
29     2
 0     4
19     4
19     3
48     9
48     4
21     5
```

where each column is a feature.  This is the function I've created thus far for tss:

```
tot_sumoSq <- function(data){

  avg = mean( as.matrix(data) )
  r = matrix(avg, nrow(data), ncol(data))

  tot_sumoSq = sum( (data - r)^2 )

}
```

I receive the result 24342.4, but R gives 13244.8.  Am I completely missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latter value is calculated using the column means.  If you use this for calculating the means, you'll get the same answer.

```
  avg = colMeans(data)
  r = matrix(avg, nrow(data), ncol(data), byrow=T)
[1] 13244.8
```

Comment: Thank you.  This clarified a lot.

Answer (score 0):

May be there are something wrong in your program. You subtract a matrix from a data frame. Use the following -

```
tot_sumoSq <- function(data){
  data = as.matrix(data)
  x = sum((data - mean(data))^2)
  return(x)
}
```

From my side it gives the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you.  This didn't fix my issue, but it did help me find a solution!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my issue by combining solutions provided by the first two commentators.  I see what my previous mistake was and would like to  clear any confusion for future scientists.

```
tot_sumoSq <- function(data){

  avg = colMeans(data)
  r = matrix(avg, nrow(data), ncol(data), byrow = T)

  data = as.matrix(data)

  return( sum( (data - r)^2 ) )

}
```

Each column is the entire sample for different features, so when we calculate the mean for each column, it is the mean of means for the entire sample for one feature.  My conceptual mistake earlier was to combine both features to calculate an overall mean.